# use dependency injection with flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: flask, dependency-injection, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am looking for a way to use simple dependency injection in combination with `flask-sqlalchemy`

Here's an example setup

extensions.py

```
db = SQLAlchemy()
```

my_model.py

```
from extensions import db

class MyModel(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    // ... some more fields
```

my_model_repository.py

```
from my_model import MyModel

class MyModelRepository:

    def get_all():
        MyModel.query.all()
```

Now I would like to somehow inject the `db` into `MyModelRepository` so that when I unit test it I can inject a `mock` or an in-memory database without having to deal with any global config or flags.

Here's an example of how I would want it to look

```
from my_model import MyModel

class MyModelRepository:

    def __init__(self, db):
        self.db = db

    def get_all():
        db.query(MyModel).all()
```

This however seems to not be possible because `MyModel` inherits from `db.Model` and `db` already is a specific instance of `SQLAlchemy`.

What is the appropriate way to make the database injectable to any component that depends on it?

Comment: Seems like you are foregoing the advantage of Flask-SqlAlchemy. You can get rid of it and use the declarative base from sqlalchemy directly if you are creating a repository layer. But you will need to also manage session yourself between a request lifecycle

Comment: I have the same requirements and thoughts. [dependency-injector](https://pypi.org/project/dependency-injector/) seems nice, as principles are clearly explained, and there is dedicated stuff for Flask, thought could not (yet) solve/understand the database injection. I'm currently looking at [flask-injector](https://pypi.org/project/Flask-Injector/), documentation reading in-progress...

Comment: as @SomeTypeFoo suggested we are now using vanilla SQLAlchemy and it works. We are not even using the declarativ_base of SQLAlchemy anymore and instead use classical mapping to gain full control Interesting articles: https://www.cosmicpython.com/book/chapter_02_repository.html, https://towardsdatascience.com/use-flask-and-sqlalchemy-not-flask-sqlalchemy-5a64fafe22a4 The first article was specifically helpful and has a corresponding github repo with good examples

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked something like this:

- In `my_model_repository.py` add the inject decorator to the init of your class

```
from my_model import MyModel
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

class MyModelRepository:
    @inject
    def __init__(self, db: SQLAlchemy):
        self.db = db

    def get_all():
        db.query(MyModel).all()
```

- and in your `app.py` or another source file where you create your flask app add:

```
import flask_injector
from extensions import db

app = Flask(__name__) #something like this should already be in your code

db.init_app(app)

#this function could potentially be moved to it's own file
def configure_dependencies(binder):
    binder.bind(SQLAlchemy, to=db, scope=flask_injector.singleton)

flask_injector.FlaskInjector(app=app, modules=[configure_dependencies])
```

Data sources:

- https://pypi.org/project/Flask-Injector/
- https://www.pythonfixing.com/2022/04/fixed-circular-import-of-db-reference.html